# Diff a git fork

Tags: git, diff

I'm reviewing a set of forks from an original git project and trying to determine the actual differences. Is there a way to do some sort of `git diff original-uri fork-uri` to get the differences between the current state of the original project and the current state of the fork?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you add the fork as a remote repository, you can make diff on it:

```
git remote add original original-uri
git fetch original
git diff HEAD original/master
```

However this requires to clone the forked repository, don't know how to do without cloning.

Comment: @Paul Alexander: it's the third command, I just forgot the `diff` :)

Comment: Not that it's a big deal, but the `..` there isn't necessary - `git diff` can take two arguments just like you'd expect from a traditional diff: `git diff HEAD original/master`.